# Will deactivating my Facebook account break the developer apps I have created?

Tags: facebook

I'm wanting to deactivate my Facebook account but I have a number of developer applications I've created which cannot be deleted.

I've added a number of users as Admins of the Apps, but as I am the owner of these apps, will deactivating the account cause the apps to stop working or get deleted?

Answer (score 2):

I think you will not able to deactivate your account if you are the ***only*** developer of any application. Probably you will get a message something like this:

*Unable to deactivate your account because you are the only developer of a Platform application. Please either delete the application or assign a new owner before deactivating your account.*

So to deactivate your account you have to delete those applications or assign a new owner for that.

Note: Deactivating Facebook account will not delete anything(likes, comments, games, game scores) associated with that account. It will deactivate everything and when you will reactivate your account, after sometime it will reactivate everything.